# Text Based JavaScript game to be placed in textarea tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am JavaScript beginner and it's really hard to learn and code JavaScript, atleast for me! I wanted to make JavaScript text based RPG game but... I want all the dialogs and text of the game to go to the `<textarea>` tag but I don't know how to make it. As I said I am beginner in JavaScript and I'm still learning! Hope you understood, here's my code:

```js
var playerName, playerHealth, playerDamage;
var enemies, enemyName, enemyHealth, enemyDamage;

// Player's stats
playerHealth = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
playerDamage = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

// Enemies
enemies = ["Slime", "Bandit", "Skeleton", "Golem"];

// Enemy's stats
enemyName = enemies[Math.floor(Math.random()*enemies.length)];
enemyHealth = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
enemyDamage = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

// The game begins here
function startGame() {
    document.getElementById("happening").value = enemyName + " appeared!";
    document.getElementById("happening").value = "What will you do?";
}
```

```css
textarea {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    resize: none;
}
input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 17px;
}
input[type=button] {
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Text Based RPG Game</title>
</head>

<body align="center" onload="startGame();">
    <textarea id="happening"></textarea><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="playerChoice" value="" placeholder="Your choice..."><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="attack" value="Attack">
    <input type="button" id="defend" value="Defend">
    <input type="button" id="run" value="Run">
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to keep this site a quality resource, we adhere to certain standards. For example, we expect people to do some [research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+write+to+textarea&t=lm&atb=v72-6&ia=qa) before asking, and we have a guide to outline [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We will not be able to answer your question if it doesn't meet the required standards.

Comment: Are you trying to just append the text content each time? i.e. use `doc.getElById("happening").value += ...` instead of just `=`

Comment: If I like attack when it's my turn, I want to print like `"You attacked " + enemyName"` on that same textarea but I could only print text in the textarea once, it won't print all text it needs. I want to print there the enemies, attacking, defensing, running... Do you understand now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would not face the uphill battle integrating game mechanics within HTML tags that are meant for something entirely different.

To achieve a similar effect you could create boxes (PNG images or drawn with code) that look like a text area and then script your game elements into those areas on the page. You could even map a < canvas > tag to match those areas for more functionality. It would allow for more graphic options and it would free you from having to deal with the < textarea > as your canvas/game space. I really like the effect though, it'd be pretty cool if you pulled it off with < textarea > tags. I just think it would be a nightmare to deal with that tag as a game canvas.

Best of luck

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I will try to make it in canvas!

Comment: np! sometimes game dev questions sometimes dont go over well here. trying to do my part